# Using Ionic and Firebase : How do you loop thought JSON and Post that data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, firebase

So I'm creating a app for a school project and hit a barrier. I'm sending up data to firebase and receiving it. But I'm having trouble accessing and posting that data correctly. Im not sure if I'm using ng-repeat correctly or accessing the json data correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is how my Json is when I retrieve it for firebase.

```
{
     "K40141w4Y3BqB9YkGGo" : [ {
        "age_range" : {
          "min" : 21
        },
        "email" : "test@gmail.com",
        "first_name" : "test",
        "gender" : "male",
        "id" : "123456789",
        "last_name" : "test",
        "link" : "test.com",
        "locale" : "en_US",
        "name" : "test test",
        "picture" : {
          "data" : {
            "is_silhouette" : false,
            "url" : "test.com"
          }
        },
        "timezone" : -5
      }, {
        "eventDesc" : "vasfasfsadfsafsa",
        "lengthOfTime" : 2,
        "location" : "test",
        "postLocation" : ""
      } ]
    }
```

Im trying to grab the first name, last name picture, eventdesc lengthOfTime and location. I'm trying to post that data to a view. Here is a JSfiddle with my html and Js https://jsfiddle.net/shcxbemh/

Comment: Please include the **minimal** code to reproduce your problem in the question itself. A jsfiddle alone is not a replacement for that (especially not if the fiddle doesn't run).

Comment: The code you provided doesn't work. It needs all the dependencies and proper app bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0):

K40141w4Y3BqB9YkGGo is an array, so probably

```
something.K40141w4Y3BqB9YkGGo[0].first_name
```